# Counting comma separated values using Emacs

Tags: emacs, csv

Is it possible to count the number of comma separated values between two marked points in a file using emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go the easy way: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `count-matches` `,`. It counts commas, but the number of values should be this number, or plus or minus one, depending on whether either point is a comma itself. I'm using Transient Mark Mode so the function applies automatically to the region.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do `narrow-to-region` followed by `(count-matches ",")`.

(Of course, a function could be written that does this in one step if you need it often. It could even add the necessary +1 for you, or deal with escaped fields between the commas, etc... But this is the fastest way I know using standard definitions.)

Comment: I can select an area of text between point and mark, then C-x n n to narrow, but how do I then apply the (count-matches ",") bit?

Comment: Hiett: That's simply the lisp syntax for a function call. Interactive functions (aka "commands") can be invoked via `M-x`, but all functions (interactive or not) can be invoked directly with elisp. The simplest way to interactively evaluate an arbitrary elisp form is with `M-:`. You can also use `C-h f count-matches` to find out more about that function (including whether it's interactive; although in this instance you need to follow the link to the `how-many` function, because `count-matches` is an alias for that).